# Jenkins check file exists inside zip file

Tags: jenkins, curl, artifactory

is there a way to check a file exists inside a zip file without unzip it. I'm using Artifactory . if use curl can't. can advice me,

I tried below

```
 sh(script: "curl -o /dev/null -sf <antifactory url>")
```

this always return success
andbelow

```
unzip -l <file.zip> | grep -q <file name>
```

this need install unzip

Comment: Are you looking to check in the zip in Artifactory only? Or you want to check on a local file you have?

Comment: Check in antifactory.  I tried curl -o /dev/null. but it does not works . My first choice is antifactory , if cant. then need download the zip from antifactory and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Artifactory 7.15.3 as mentioned in [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.15.3) archive search is disabled by default. Can you confirm if you are version above this. If yes, you can enable this feature by Navigating to Admin > Artifactory > Archive Search Enabled and enable this checkbox. But please be aware that, if we enable this feature, it keeps writing a lot of information to the database for every archive file and can impact the performance.

Later you can search items in a zip file. Below is an example command where I am searching for .class files in my zip from curl. You may opt similar to this in Jenkis.

```
$ curl -uadmin:password -X GET "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/search/archive?name=*.class&repos=test" -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of bash commands `unzip` and `grep`.

```
unzip -l my_file.zip | grep -q file_to_search

# Example 
$ unzip -l 99bottles.zip | grep -q 99bottles.pdf && echo $?
0
```

P.S. If zip contains directory structure, then grep with full path of the file name

Comment: Hi unzip we need install additional package. Is there a way to do without unzip -l. I saw this earlier, but unzip need to be installed